# oracle wmconcat,listagg function report string length exceed 4000 bytes error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Our web project has crashed serveral times because of this problem.Most answers online suggests using xmlagg or clob,but still too troublesome.
So how can i rewrite a function like wmconcat or listagg that will only display the first few  words in order to avoid the problem,the rest of the words will be replaced by ellipses?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to *skip the concatenation* as soon as the length approaches 4000 characters.

Firstly, you need to find the running sum of length of the column you intend to append, following a particular ORDER. Find the *maximum number* of rows in that order, that you could afford to append before it reaches close to 3500 characters( excluding commas in the final string).

Next, concatenate the string using the same order using `LISTAGG` limiting to the number of rows found in the first step.

```
WITH cte(maxrows)
     AS (SELECT Max(rn)
         FROM   (SELECT row_number()
                          over (
                            ORDER BY rcol ) rn,
                        SUM(Length(rcol))
                          over (
                            ORDER BY rcol)  total_length
                 FROM   yourtable)
         WHERE  total_length < 3500),

    ltd AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT rcol,
                        maxrows,
                        row_number()
                          over (
                            ORDER BY rcol ) rn
                 FROM   yourtable
                        cross join cte)
         WHERE  rn <= maxrows)
SELECT LISTAGG(rcol, ',') 
         within GROUP ( ORDER BY rcol ) less_than_4000
FROM   ltd;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4307d4/60)

**Note**: If you have duplicate entries in the column, it is advisable to take a `DISTINCT` set before the start of above processing, assuming that you won't need multiple values for a record in the concatenation.

Comment: Our project has almost completed and is ready to be deployed for use.Some of the queries in my project are so complex that i can not adopt your method into my queries.Is it possible to write a function that just work like wmconcat so i can simply replace 'wmconcat' with the function i wrote.

Comment: SELECT 
       CAST(
           RTRIM(
               EXTRACT(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("c", x.cust_id || ',') ORDER BY 1), '/c/text()').getclobval(),
               ','
           ) AS VARCHAR2(4000)
       )
           AS f3_list
  FROM (select * from acrm_f_ci_customer where rownum between 1 and 4000) x
GROUP BY 1

Comment: XMLAGG seems not working, it will also report  'string too long' error.

Comment: @abracadabra you could create a function that returns  CLOB. Its performance is not as good as  listagg, but it works. u will find many implementations online.